# MySQL insert from select query

Tags: mysql, insert

I have two tables:

TABLE1

```
| ColumnA  | ColumnB  |
-----------------------
| 123      | 1        |
```

TABLE2

```
| ColumnA  | ColumnC  |
-----------------------
| 123      | 20       |
```

I altered Table 2 to add a new column, so it looks like this

NEW TABLE2

```
| ColumnA  | ColumnC  | ColumnB  |
----------------------------------
| 123      | 20       | NULL     |
```

Now, I want to select the values of `TABLE1.Column B` and insert it into `TABLE2.Column B`

So I wrote this query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ColumnB)
SELECT t1.ColumnB
FROM TABLE1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
TABLE2 AS t2
ON t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA;
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick. Am I missing something?

Comment: can't insert/update on a table you're selecting from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an UPDATE statement to update the table. An INSERT will add new rows.

```
UPDATE Table2
JOIN Table1
ON
Table2.columnA = Table1.ColumnA
SET 
Table2.ColumnB = Table1.ColumnB
WHERE
Table2.ColumnB IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Strangely, I keep getting a syntax error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table1 INNER JOIN table1.columnA = table2.columnA WHERE table2.columnB i' at line 5

Comment: Oops, didn't notice this was MySQL and not MSSQL. The updated query should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That did not work either, but I made a few minor edits and it worked. (See edits above)

Comment: @Spartanblogger duh, obvious mistake on my part. Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score -2):

You don't appear to want to insert. It appears you want to update the rows already in table2. You can use:

```
update table2 set ColumbB=(select ColumnB from table1 where table1.ColumnA=table2.ColumnA)
```

Comment: introducing a subquery here is not necessary, and in this case even leads to wrong results.

Comment: @Hazzit in this case, I don't believe that query will even run, but if it does every row will have the same value.

Comment: I know that it will run because I tested it before posting the answer. A subquery is never the fastest solution, but it is often the easiest to understand for someone who is learning.

Comment: @kainaw well if it runs it's going to put the same value in ColumnB for every record.

Comment: Instead of thinking what it might do, just do it. I made a two tables, filled them with data, and used this query. It worked.